# Cycles mixed material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, normal-map

I have a problem with setting up a mixed material for a bottle label I need.

The label will need some different surfaces;
- Diffuse (the base paper) preferably with a normal map for adding the paper feel to it.
- Glossy (the golden text and details), preferably with a normal map for adding a bevelled feeling.

I have all parts isolated in different PNGs/TIFFs.

Now, is it possible or even a good idea to set this up in the same material? Or should I go for different materials on the same object (and if so, please guide me)?

[image: Note: The attached bottle label is just an example - not the actual design I will use in the end. But it shows what kind of different materials/textures I need on the label.]

---

Very nice results with your setup @bstnhnsl! I think it produces exactly what I need. (sorry for answering my own question, but I didn't know how to post an image sample otherwise).

[image: Render sample]

One question, though: You mentioned that one can use an unlimited amount of material this way, and I've tried but I don't think I get it; should I use one more Mix shader to add for instance one more texture image?

Comment: Since there even seems to be a slight bump to the surface of logo I'd go with a full modelling, solution if you brother to trace the logo. It seems relatively simple in terms of geometry anyway. That way you don't have to bother with lots of textures and complex material setups, just make a separate material for each part

Comment: Thank you Duarte! Well, sometimes it can be quite complex logos and fonts, which would add quite some faces to the scene if you made models/meshes out of them...

Comment: DON'T model that. It's a pain in the arse if you want to change the logo or the text or whatever. With the texture-method you are absolute flexible in absolute everything... And imho it's way easier if you got the hang of it.

Answer (score 1):

I do a lot of similar things (book mockups with different finishings for presentations etc.). The way to go is definitely a setup in the same material. The idea is for each material to have its own shader and mix them together with a mix-shader-node and a bw-image (the white parts of the image represent one material, the black parts the other material).
If the logo changes you can simply swap the image for the mix-nodes.

**This is the image I used for the mix-node:**

[image: Mix-Node-Image]

**This is the general node setup:**

- the blue part defines which parts are gold and which are bricks
- yellow and red are the different materials (you can add normal maps, bump-maps, albedo etc...)

[image: Node Setup]

**and the final result:**
(I just grabbed a brick-texture for demonstration-purposes)

[image]

A few tips: to add realism you can use the mix-node-image as a bump-map for your gold-ink-material and mix the normal maps of the different materials.
you are also not limited to 2 materials, just add another material and another mix-node with a mask... unlimited materials. yay

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you for your answer, @bstnhnsl! Very explanatory and thorough, top notch!

Comment: Very nice results with your setup @bstnhnsl! I think it produces exactly what I need.